# Pandas: Efficiently splitting entries

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a Pandas `dataframe` with columns as such:

event_id, obj_0_type, obj_0_foo, obj_0_bar, obj_1_type, obj_1_foo, obj_1_bar, obj_n_type, obj_n_foo, obj_n_bar, ....

For example:

```
col_idx = ['event_id']
[col_idx.extend(('obj_%d_id' %d, 'obj_%d_foo' %d, 'obj_%d_bar' %d)) for d in range(5)]
event_id = np.array(range(0,5))
data = np.random.rand(15,5)
data = np.vstack((event_id, data))
df = DataFrame(data.T, index = range(5), columns = col_idx)
```

I would like to split each individual row of the dataframe so that I'd have a single entry per object, as such:

event_id, obj_type, obj_foo, obj_bar

Where event_id would be shared among all the objects of a given event.

There are lots of very slow ways of doing it (iterating over the dataframe rows and creating new series objects) but those are atrociously slow and obviously unpythonic.  Is there a simpler way I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

With some suggestions from some people in #pydata on freenode, this is what I came up with:

```
data = []
for d in range(5):
    temp = df.ix[:, ['event_id', 'obj_%d_id' % d, 'obj_%d_foo' % d, 'obj_%d_bar' % d]]
    temp.columns = ['event_id', 'obj_id', 'obj_foo', 'obj_bar']
    # Giving columns unique names.
    temp.index = temp['event_id']*10 + d
    # Creating a unique index.
    data.append(temp)

concat(data)
```

This works and is reasonably fast!